# exception when trying to set broadcast flag

Tags: macos, node.js, networking, udp

I'm working on a dhcp server/client and wanted to try stuff in my home network.
I want to send a `DHCPDISCOVER` message via udp into my network and catch the answer from my router. Here is my code:

```
var sender = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
sender.bind();
sender.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});

sender.setBroadcast(true);

var listener = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
listener.bind(68, function() {
  console.log('BOUND');
});
listener.on('message', function(msg, rinfo) {
  console.log(msg);
});

sender.send(message, 0, message.length, 67, "255.255.255.255");
```

But when I try to set the broadcast flag my application crashes.

```
sudo node main

dgram.js:345
    throw errnoException(process._errno, 'setBroadcast');
          ^
Error: setBroadcast EBADF
    at errnoException (dgram.js:454:11)
    at Socket.setBroadcast (dgram.js:345:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/Projects/node-dhcp-server/node_modules/module-dhcp/main.js:31:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
felix@felixs-macbook-pro:/Volumes/Projects/node-dhcp-server/node_modules/module-dhcp%
```

I have no idea why it crashes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm ok this was an obvious fault ...
Of course the `bind()` method is asynchronous and I have to set the flag in the callback.

```
sender.bind( function() { sender.setBroadcast(true) } );
```