# How to know who is connected to my wifi in nodejs

Tags: node.js, wifi, network-scan

I'd like to know how is possible in nodejs to scan my wifi and return all the MAC-address of all the devices connected.
I'm trying with SNMP module but doesn't work...

Comment: Does your router have an exposed method of retrieving the list? Many cheap routers may not support SNMP. I know with several cheap routers I've had that the only way would be to "scrape" an HTML page that contained the list. You said the "SNMP" module didn't work. What did you specifically try?

Comment: possible duplicate of [exception when trying to set broadcast flag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291172/exception-when-trying-to-set-broadcast-flag)